# Simple PHP MySQL code, value is not identified by MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a website eCommerce website but I am stuck with this no-so working PHP and MySQL code,

Let's say, $_GET["pid"] is from URL sent from other page with given value of 111
and $_POST["submit"] is a Form's submit button from a same page.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "users_database");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users_products"));

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $pid = $_GET["pid"];    
    $sql_update = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users_products SET product_name='$_POST[product_name]' WHERE id=$pid");
    header("location: admin_home.php");
}
?>
```

The code will work if i change "WHERE id=$pid" to exact number such as "WHERE id=100". I believe there is a problem with the value "$pid" and needed to be change to other method?

Comment: there isn't enough code here to give you a solid solution. No way to know where `$_GET["pid"]` is coming from, seems like a form you didn't post.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No clarification yet, looks like OP went for some *coffee*. :-)

Comment: Assuming that your code is making it to the `mysqli_query` function call, I would move the query string into a variable `$q="UPDATE ..."`, print that variable to your web page, and run the query directly in the database engine, using MySQL Workbench or whatever client you use, to see if it generates any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Change the string:

```
"UPDATE users_products SET product_name='$_POST[product_name]' WHERE id=$pid"
```

to this

```
"UPDATE users_products SET product_name='" .$_POST[product_name]. "' WHERE id=" .$pid
```

The issue is due to you're not passing the value of $pid but the string $pid itself.

Comment: I tried your solution and still its doesnt work at all. Thanks.

Comment: can you print $sql_update and post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `intval()` function to get the integer value of the variable, like this:

```
$pid = intval($_GET["pid"]);
```

Here's the reference:

- [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: This one should works but unfortunately it doesnt and it does change it to integer. Thanks anyway!